# clerk every time when navigating to a page he fetches

Tags: clerk

I use this function:

```
// or, if you also need a custom loader handler:
export const loader: LoaderFunction = (args) => {
  return rootAuthLoader(
    args,
    ({ request }) => {
      console.log(request.auth);
      const { userId } = request.auth;
      // fetch data
      const user = await getUserByUserID(request.auth);
      return { uid: user.id };
    },
    { loadUser: true }
  );
};
```

So my fetch takes 500ms, so on every page it fetches and waits 500ms, why can he not save it once in cookie and then get the data via a clerk function or cookie ?

Comment: It can.  You just need to only run the function if whatever you want set across all page isn't set.  it looks like you're exporting `loader` so just check to see `if something exists()` else run `loader` and **set** `something` from within the `LoaderFunction`